# How to use custom macro indentation in elisp?

Tags: elisp, indentation

This [blog post](http://oremacs.com/2015/01/28/notes-on-elisp-indentation/) shows that its possible to indent like this:

```elisp
(lispy-dotimes arg
  (when (= (point) (point-max))
    (error "Reached end of buffer"))
  (forward-list))
```

Instead of this:

```elisp
(lispy-dotimes arg
               (when (= (point) (point-max))
                 (error "Reached end of buffer"))
               (forward-list))
```

The post has some snippets but not a enough for a beginner to change their emacs configuration.

How would a typical emacs mode hook be modified to indent like this? eg:

```elisp
(add-hook
 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   ;; stuff goes here!
   ))
```

Comment: Evaluating that macro will do that as it contains an indentation declaration.

Comment: I tried evaluating the macro linked and it didnt change indentation behavior.

Comment: The blog post only shows the definition of `lispy-save-excursion`, evaluating that will only change indentation of calls to `lispy-save-excursion`.  If you want to fix the indentation of `lispy-dotimes`, you'll have to actually retrieve its source, eval its definition and reindent the example.

Answer (score 2):

You can control such indentation using options `lisp-indent-offset` and `lisp-body-indent`, option `lisp-indent-function`, or symbol property `lisp-indent-function`.  One possible value for option `lisp-indent-function` is the value of  `common-lisp-indent-function`.

See the Emacs manual, node [Lisp Indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Indent.html) (and its parent node, [Program Indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Program-Indent.html)), for more information.

See also standard library `cl-indent.el`.

For example:

```el
(defun lisp-indentation-hack ()
  "Your Lisp indenting.  Use in Lisp mode hooks
such as `lisp-mode-hook', `emacs-lisp-mode-hook', and
`lisp-interaction-mode-hook'."
  (unless (load-history-filename-element (load-history-regexp "cl-indent"))
    (load "cl-indent" nil t))
  (set (make-local-variable 'lisp-indent-function) 'common-lisp-indent-function)
  (setq lisp-indent-maximum-backtracking  10)
  (put 'define-derived-mode 'common-lisp-indent-function '(4 4 4 2 &body))
  (put 'if 'common-lisp-indent-function '(nil nil &body))
  (when (featurep 'cl-indent)
    (put 'cl-flet 'common-lisp-indent-function
         (get 'flet 'common-lisp-indent-function))
    (put 'cl-labels 'common-lisp-indent-function
         (get 'labels 'common-lisp-indent-function))))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'lisp-indentation-hack)
```